# Get customer order count excluding failures - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using `if ( wc_get_customer_order_count( get_current_user_id() ) != 0 ){` to check if a customer has ordered before. If they haven't, I apply a first order discount in the cart.

However, there have been a few occurrences where a new customer's order will fail (mostly due to lack of funds). Then, when they try to re-order, the discount isn't applied because "**wc_get_customer_order_count**" includes failed orders.

Is there a way exclude failed orders when using this function?

Answer (score 1):

you can get any type of user orders by checking 'post-status' of orders
like this:

```
// specify the type of order you need. (delete any item that you dont need)
$order_status = array('wc-pending', 'wc-processing', 'wc-on-hold', 'wc-completed', 'wc-cancelled', 'wc-refunded', 'wc-failed');
$user_orders= wc_get_orders( array(
    'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value' => $current_user->ID,
    'post_status' => $order_status,
    'numberposts' => -1,
) );
```

then check the result and do somthing ...

```
if (!empty($user_orders)){
     //your code
    }
```

Comment: Any plugin can add new statusses, so this wouldn't work if you have other statusses. I don't know if there is a way to search by excluding statusses, other than retrieving all orders and filtering out in code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I found a way to do it, even if other plugins have added new status types:

```
$order_statuses = wc_get_order_statuses();
$order_statuses = array_diff_key($order_statuses, array(
    'wc-failed'     => '',
    // add any other statuses you want to exclude (you just need the key)
    )
);

$query_args = array(
    'limit'         => -1, // to retrieve all
    'customer_id'   => 12, // or use 'customer' => 'some@email.com'
    'status'        => array_keys($order_statuses) // use only the keys
);

$orders = wc_get_orders($query_args);
```

This will get you all orders for that customer, without the failed ones.